# subsetting all values in a dataframe by delimiter

Tags: r, dataframe, substr

Data looks like

```
> loc.dat[1:2,1:3]
              imageNumber.1             imageNumber.2             imageNumber.3
1         latitude=34.73388         latitude=34.73393    latitude=34.7339966667
2 longitude=-106.7133033333 longitude=-106.7128583333 longitude=-106.7123566667
```

I have been trying to

```
df <- unlist(strsplit(loc.dat, '=', fixed=TRUE))[2]
```

but this is not working due to

```
Error in strsplit(loc.dat, "=", fixed = TRUE) : non-character argument
```

I have tried lapply and a for loop but its not working. I am sure it is simple but I haven't run into this issue before.

Does anyone have a better solution for this?

Comment: If you don't care about storing the part before the "=" you can simply remove the text before "=" by using gsub and using the regex pattern "^.+="

Answer (score 1):

`strsplit` can not be applied directly on data frame. You can use `lapply` to loop through columns. Here is a method with `lapply` and `tstrsplit` from `data.table`, supposing all the columns are of character class instead of factor:

```
library(data.table)
loc.dat[] = lapply(loc.dat, function(col) tstrsplit(col, "=")[[2]])
loc.dat
#    imageNumber.1   imageNumber.2   imageNumber.3
#1        34.73388        34.73393   34.7339966667
#2 -106.7133033333 -106.7128583333 -106.7123566667
```